# Django: Custom mail list

Tags: django

I need to make a list of users that receive emails when an event occurs. This list should also be modifiable by admins.

What's the Django way to do this if I'm using sqlite? My first thought was to create a new table for the mail list and throw it somewhere in the admin panel but this seems to be a bit of an inefficient method? Is Django `groups` the way to go in this situation? Or a many-to-many relationship between a groups table and users? Or something else perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want admins to be able to update the mail list then `groups` are ideal for this.